# Date Diff in the same column, based on the value of the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following is the format of the table.

```
Id     name    value      logdatetime
*************************************************
1       a       65         2017-03-08 00:13:00.000
2       a       63         2017-03-08 00:14:00.000
3       a       72         2017-03-08 00:15:00.000
4       a       120        2017-03-08 00:16:00.000
5       a       45         2017-03-08 00:17:00.000
6       a       32         2017-03-08 00:18:00.000
7       a       53         2017-03-08 00:19:00.000
8       a       59         2017-03-08 00:20:00.000
9       a       21         2017-03-08 00:21:00.000
```

From the above table I need to generate the following table using an sql query, it basically have to check for the value greater than 50 and display the data as follows

```
name     startdate                           enddate
********************************************************************
a        2017-03-08 00:13:00.000             2017-03-08 00:16:00.000
a        2017-03-08 00:19:00.000             2017-03-08 00:21:00.000
```

Please help me out in this query.

Comment: Please clarify that how the startdate and enddate has been generated ?

Comment: How are you specifiying start and end date?

Comment: I think `2017-03-08 00:21` is wrong in your result. And right is `2017-03-08 00:20`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData(
  Id int,
  name varchar(10),
  value int,
  logdatetime datetime
)

INSERT #TestData(Id,name,value,logdatetime)VALUES
(1,'a',65,'2017-03-08 00:13:00.000'),
(2,'a',63,'2017-03-08 00:14:00.000'),
(3,'a',72,'2017-03-08 00:15:00.000'),
(4,'a',120,'2017-03-08 00:16:00.000'),
(5,'a',45,'2017-03-08 00:17:00.000'), -- separator 1
(6,'a',32,'2017-03-08 00:18:00.000'), -- separator 2
(7,'a',53,'2017-03-08 00:19:00.000'),
(8,'a',59,'2017-03-08 00:20:00.000'),
(9,'a',21,'2017-03-08 00:21:00.000') -- separator 3


SELECT
  name,
  MIN(logdatetime) [start time],
  MAX(logdatetime) [end time]
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      SUM(IsSeparator)OVER(
                            PARTITION BY name
                            ORDER BY logdatetime,Id
                            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                          ) SeparatorCount
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          *,
          --IIF(value<=50,1,0) IsSeparator -- it's a special marker
          CASE WHEN value<=50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IsSeparator -- you can use CASE instead IIF
        FROM #TestData
      ) q
  ) q
WHERE value>50 -- exclude values less 50
GROUP BY name,SeparatorCount -- use SeparatorCount here

DROP TABLE #TestData
```

I tested it on `SQLServer 2014`.

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ff80e/1

Or you can use another variant with recursive CTE

```
;WITH numCTE AS(
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY logdatetime,Id) n
  FROM #TestData
),
groupCTE AS(
  SELECT name,logdatetime,value,n,1 groupNum
  FROM numCTE
  WHERE n=1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT n.name,n.logdatetime,n.value,n.n,
    --g.groupNum+IIF(n.value<=50,1,0) 
    g.groupNum+CASE WHEN n.value<=50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
  FROM numCTE n
  JOIN groupCTE g ON n.name=g.name AND n.n=g.n+1
)
SELECT
  name,
  MIN(logdatetime) [start time],
  MAX(logdatetime) [end time]
FROM groupCTE
WHERE value>50
GROUP BY name,groupNum
```

But I think the first variant is better.

One more variant. It's shorter than the first variant.

```
SELECT
  name,
  MIN(logdatetime) [start time],
  MAX(logdatetime) [end time]
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      SUM(CASE WHEN value<=50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)OVER(
              PARTITION BY name
              ORDER BY logdatetime,Id
              ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
            ) groupNum
    FROM #TestData
  ) q
WHERE value>50
GROUP BY name,groupNum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with CTE AS(select *,CASE WHEN VALue>50 then 1 else 0 end AS cnt from #TestData)
  select DISTINCT Name,
               case when nullif(cnt,lag(Cnt)over(order by logdatetime))=1 then  logdatetime  end StartDATE,
               case when nullif(cnt,lead(Cnt)over(order by logdatetime))=1 then  logdatetime  end ENDDATE
                from CTE
```

Comment: This is not going to be the desired output

Comment: we have to wait for OP's response

Comment: Start date will be the first identified exceeded value record's logdatetime,end date will be the last identified exceeded value record's logdatetime. As the time interval of each record will be 1 minute, from the sequence of records only we have to find it. Then the next exceeded value record will be start date again, in that sequence last exceeded value record will be end date again. Hope I have not confused it more.

Comment: @santoshkumarPithani we do not have to wait for op, if you have any sql knowledge you know that this output would not be anywhere to desired. And the whole logic behind it is **** aswell

Comment: Sorry for late, i'm little busy please check updates query